# Create an array whenever an image is uploaded using url and then store a object into that array in firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to get url, caption and id of an image using an object and then store them into firestore field but the problem is, I need them to be stored into an array so I can retrieve and display the images onto my UI. Currently firestore field is returning an array

I tried to merge class object with an array, push the object into the array and using normal object instead of class object.

`

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.posts = [];
    this.post = {
      id: cuid(),
      caption: "",
      image: "",
    };
```

```
 getFileUrl(name) {
    const imageRef = storage.ref(name);
    imageRef
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        this.post.image = url;
        console.log(this.post.image);
        this.savePosts();
        this.render();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "Error Occured");
      });
  }

  savePosts() {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(this.userId)
      .set({
        post: this.posts,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    this.savePosts();
  }
```

`

[firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXDNW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If think you're looking for:

```
this.post.image.push(url);
```

If you tried that and ran intro problems, edit your question to show the exact code you tried and where you got stuck (including any error message or the erroneous result you got).

Comment: i tried the above code and it works...and it works. thank you so much frank